# How to change the humberger icon in toolbar?

Tags: android, toolbar, drawer, materialdrawer

I am using **mikepenz drawer library** but I want to change default humburger icon and back arrow icon with my own drawable icon.

I have tried many times but **I am unable to change the icon with my own icon** .

Can anyone help me ?

```
new DrawerBuilder()
    .withActivity(this)
    .withTranslucentStatusBar(false)
    .withActionBarDrawerToggle(false)
    .withToolbar(toolbar)
    .addDrawerItems(
        //pass your items here
    )
    .build();
```

CODE TO SHOW THE HUMBURGER ICON:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
result.getActionBarDrawerToggle().setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
```

following is the code I found many times but i tried this also but it did not work

```
Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable);

        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

And when I am searching I also come to know that you can not change the icon if you passing the toolbar in drawer builder so can anyone tell me what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it with that library but, try the following:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable);

            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }
```

Comment: Alright, btw format your question properly to avoid downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

As per this [link](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/issues/1240), you need to remove the `withToolbar()` from the `DrawerBuilder` and then you will have to handle open/close completely on your own.

For that you can do some thing like that

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_custom_drawer_icon);
        ...
    }
```

Also you had to add a toolbar navigation click listener to listen for click events on the custom drawer icon.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                } else {
                    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            }
        });
        ...
    }
```

You can update the icon dynamically whenever required as

```
toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_new_icon);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this by modify following:

```
 result.getActionBarDrawerToggle().setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
```

to

```
 result.getActionBarDrawerToggle().setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

this disable library default icon then change the icon...

```
 getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.my_drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
Toolbar toolbar;
String Drawer_Open,Drawer_Close;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
//set it button icon
getSuppotActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
//set it makes button Clickble
getSuppotActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
//set your own icon by using this code
getSuppotActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.my_icon);
drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
actionBarDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,Drawer_Open,Drawer_Close);
drawerLayout.serDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
}

}
```

Again Do you have any quires get Consult me here.....,hope you got solution to your problem...