# MaterialDrawer change hamburger icon(Menu)

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, materialdrawer

I am using [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) library and I trying to change the hamburger icon.
I found this answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673653/how-to-change-the-humberger-icon-in-toolbar).

but I cannot understand from the answer how to use the `toggle` variable over there and it doesn't seems to work for me.

is there any way of changing it then?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation of the library you are using you can switch between hamburger-icon to back-arrow icon with the following code snippet:

```
result.getActionBarDrawerToggle().setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I want to make a whole different icon